# Core graphics - Crear y dibujar un CALayer

Tags: ios, swift

Buenas, estoy teniendo un problema que no tira ningún error por consola, simplemente Xcode va AppDelegate con una línea el rojo. 
Estoy tratando de crear un `UIButton`con un sublayer el cual debería ser un circulo bordeando al botón(el cual sería también un círculo). 
Lo que hice casa ahora de código es lo siguiente:

```
//
//  PhotoButtonView.swift
//  PhotoChat
//
//  Created by ... on 10/9/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 ... . All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class PhotoButtonView: UIButton {



    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.createCircleLayer(To: self)

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.createCircleLayer(To: self)
    }

    private func createCircleLayer(To view: UIView) {
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.name = "CircleLayer"

        let circleLayerDelegate = CircleLayerDelegate()

        layer.delegate = circleLayerDelegate

        layer.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)//Se toma el frame del layer, en relación a las cordenadas del padre.
        layer.frame.size = view.frame.size



        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }



    class CircleLayerDelegate: NSObject, CALayerDelegate {

        var fillColor: CGColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

        func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
            if layer.name == "CircleLayer" {
                ctx.setLineWidth(10)
                ctx.setFillColor(fillColor)
                ctx.setStrokeColor(fillColor)
                ctx.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
                ctx.fillPath()
                ctx.strokePath()
            }
        }  

    }

}
```

Se que hay muchas maneras de hacerlo pero quiero ver de entender como funciona el delegado(que es la línea que si comento no hay error).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes establecer un *Exception Breakpoint* de manera que *Xcode* detendrá la ejecución justo antes de la excepción, así puedes investigar mejor qué ocurre.

Debug/Breakpoints/Create Exception Breakpoint